# How to pluralize this sentence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display the number of followers a user has.

My original code was `<h5><%= current_user.followers.count %> followers<h5>`

This produces the incorrect statement: "1 followers"

How to pluralize this sentence? I experimented with the following and I can't get it to work.

```
<%= 'follower'.pluralize(current_user.followers.count) %>
```

This displays just the word "follower" and no number in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<%= pluralize(current_user.followers.count, 'follower') %>
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize